# Connect node js server with android

Tags: android, node.js, express, authentication

I need to make android registration/authentification with node.js. In server side i use express, mysql, what else i must use on the server to connect with android app? Please help me, i'm new on this.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to connect android application with server is [Retrofit.](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) You can find multiple tutorials in internet for this. This is maximum used by all android developers.

[Tutorial 1](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial)

[Tutorial 2](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Answer (score 1):

On nodejs side use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for authentication(use any npm jwt package), once user enters credentials in app send then to the nodejs server, if they are valid, send a JWT token to the client(android app), save the token in local preferences(app side), while making subsequent requests use jwt in your request header, so that nodejs can authenticate your app/user.
android side its better to use retrofit to make network requests.
data you send from or to server should be in [JSON](https://www.json.org/) fromat.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to nodejs server, I have used volley library in the android to make rest API calls and at the node.js I have used express to create API routes and body-parser to read the data sent from the android using HTTP methods. For authentication, I have jsonwebtoken in node.js and sharedpreferences in android to store the session at the client end.

if you want full tutorial check the [link](https://programcoaster.blogspot.com/2019/11/user-registration-using-nodejs-and-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the retrofit library its faster than volley. Retrofit can perform Async and sync requests with automatic JSON parsing without any effort.

All you need to include the dependency in your gradle file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'


compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

create the model and interface for the same and you are good to go.